# Deploying .NetCore3.1 API to LinuxCentos(Nginx)

Tags: angular, api, nginx, deployment, centos

I am trying to deploy .NET Core 3.1 API + Angular to Linux Centos it runs on the server but browser cant open it properly. If I publish the same project for windows and run it with cmd it runs no problem. When I deploy it I get this cases according to what I put in nginx configuration:

```
localhost:5020/weatherforcast - > I get the API's built in json returning functionality.
localhost:5020/Index.html - > I get index html but only <title> loads and *.js and *.css is not found /so blank white screen with bar title/.
localhost:5020 - > I get 404
```

I also do not have any routing at all.
This is how my startup Configure method  looks like:
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.EnvironmentName == Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Environments.Development)
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&   !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                await next();
            }
        });

     //   if (env.EnvironmentName == Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Environments.Development) app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        if (env.EnvironmentName == Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Environments.Development)
        {
            app.UseCors(builder => builder
                       .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowCredentials()
                       );
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
        }


        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseHsts();
        app.UseResponseCompression();

        app.UseMiddleware<Middlewares.SeederMiddleware>();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<RecievedMessagesHub>("/unread-messages");
            endpoints.MapHub<RecipeDetailsTrackHub>("/recipe-details");
        });
    }
```

and this is my Nginx setting:

```
server {
listen        80;
server_name  app123.tk www.app123.tk;
location / {
    proxy_pass         https://localhost:5020;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

And this is what Nginx logs say:

```
[error] 5349#0: *92 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while   connecting to upstream,    client: X.X.X.X, server: app123.tk, request: "GET  / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:5020/",  host: "www.app123.tk".
```

I have no such problems if I run non angular app MVC on the same port with same Nginx setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my problem: 
below

```
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

I added

```
proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
proxy_buffering off;
```